# How do I *un*set an option in `xkbmap`?

Tags: x11, keyboard-shortcuts, xkb

I would like to disable the Ctrl-Alt-Backspace combination using a command line tool, without root priviliges.

I know I can use `setxkbmap` to *en*able “zapping” with the option `terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp`.  Further, `setxkbmap -option` [naming no option]  removes *all* options.  Is there a way to unset only one option?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/29603/how-do-i-clear-xmodmap-settings) will help.

Comment: `setxkbmap -option -option $(setxkbmap -query | sed -n '/options:\s*\|terminate:[^,]*/s///gp')`

Comment: @don_crissti I hope that there is more correct decision than my crutch…

Comment: @Costas - alas, there is no straightforward way, `setxkbmap -option -option new:options` is the easiest way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A little bit crutched: remove all options using `-option` with an empty argument first, then set same options with *terminate* excluded from the list:

```
setxkbmap -option -option $(setxkbmap -query |
    sed -n 's/options:\s*\(terminate:[^:]*,\)\?\|,terminate:[^,]*//gp')
```

Comment: To be clear, I was looking for something more straightforward — like you said yourself.  It really seems there *should* be an option to do that, but if there isn't, this is The Answer.

Answer (score 7):

From my experience (limited) what worked best was using:

```
setxkbmap -query
```

And that prints out your current settings ( `setxkbmap -print` is another alternative to show your current keyboard settings)
Then delete all the options by using the `-option` without any arguments:

```
setxkbmap -option
```

Then reintroduce the new options one at time:

```
setxkbmap -option key:key_replacement
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy way:

```
setxkbmap -option
setxkbmap -option 'terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more general script, based on the accepted answer; you can pass patterns, as in `unsetxkbmap-option 'terminate:.*` or, to undo `-option ctrl:swapcaps` but preview results: `unsetxkbmap-option -n '.*swap.*'`

```
!/bin/sh -eu
DRY=
while test $# -gt 0; do case "$1" in
--dry-run|-n) shift; DRY=y ;;
--) shift; break ;;
-*) echo "Unknown: $1"; exit 1 ;;
*) break ;;
esac; done
opts=$(setxkbmap -query |
 perl -wlnE 'if (/^options:\s*/gc) { ($& =~ /'^"$1"'$/ or print "-option $& ") while /[^,]+/g }'
)
printf '%s\n' "$opts"
test -z "$DRY" && setxkbmap -option $opts
```